# Initiating a process in Java Web Application from a Oracle trigger

Tags: java, oracle, web-applications, triggers, quartz-scheduler

In a Java Web Application which has Oracle 11g at the backend, I would like to initiate execution of a program (may be a servlet) once an Oracle Stored Procedure completes it's job.

My idea is to have the procedure insert a record into a database table when it completes the job and a trigger set on the table initiates this Java process.

How can I accomplish it? If Quartz Scheduler could be used to accomplish this, then please provide pointers to how to achieve it. If not, what other options do I have?

Comment: just to shed some light, is the Oracle stored procedure started from the Java webapp in the first place?

Comment: @mrod No. The Oracle Stored Procedure is initiated from another system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used UTL_HTTP in the past to POST a request to the servlet. This has the potential benefit that it's simple and you can log/utilise the response message in the database easily enough. This will need an ACL rule to be added: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/fine-grained-access-to-network-services-11gr1.php

You could also initiate a connection from the servlet to the database, and use DBMS_ALERT signalling in your trigger: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_alert.htm This has the potential benefit that it's quick, and won't require an ACL rule.

Finally, you could use your trigger to insert a row somewhere / update a status column, and then simply have the servlet poll on an interval to see if it should do any work or not. This is the simplest of all the solutions, but isn't as elegant or as much fun to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You either can use UTL_HTTP available as part of Oracle to send a POST call to a Servlet URL from within your Oracle Stored Procedure. Find more information [here](http://awads.net/wp/2005/11/30/http-post-from-inside-oracle/)

Or you can get rid of the Servlet and write a Java Stored Procedure that can be Imported into Oracle as a stored procedure and call it. Find more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B10108_01/jdgwork.htm)